# Counting files in assets subfolders

Tags: java, android

I have a folder in `assets` folder named `s1`.There are about a hundred text file in it. I want to count how many text files are in that folder.

The application crashes at start up with this error : `

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Here is the code in `MainActivity`:

```
    Integer fileCount = 0;
    fileCount = Integer.valueOf(new File("./assets/s1/").listFiles().length);


    for(int i=0;i<fileCount;i++) {

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setId(i+1);
        btn.setText("button "+(i+1));
        btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
        final int index = i;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index);
            }
        });
        dynamicview.addView(btn);
    }
```

How to solve that?

Comment: Did you tried to debug ? For example, separate method calls of the 2nd line, and look what is the value of `new File("..")`, then the value of `.listFiles()` and so on ?

Comment: You cannot use the File class for files in assets. And the used path is wrong too. You better google for how to read a file from assets. Or how to list them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the assets like this:

```
fileCount = getResources().getAssets().list("s1").length;
```

`getResources()` returns the `Resources` instance for your app. Calling `getAssets()` on that returns the `AssetManager`. Files in the assets do not exist in the file system, so you cannot open and read them like normal files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAssets().open(path);`
And start from folder name within assets hierarchy or file name if there is no subfolder.